# trying to zip datetime64[D], getting Error : too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, zip

I am trying to zip 3 iterators -
list of high temperature values , list of low temperature values and a date index of dtype = datetime64[D].
I am using vs code.
here is my code:

```
date_index = np.arange('2015-01-01','2016-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')

(dates_high,break_high) = [(x,a) for a, b, x in zip(high, tmax, date_index) if a > b]
```

this is the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [27], line 8
      5 low = df_2015f[('Data_Value', 'min')].tolist()
      6 high = df_2015f[('Data_Value', 'max')].tolist()
----> 8 (dates_high,break_high) = [(x,a) for a, b, x in zip(high, tmax, date_index) if a > b]
      9 (dates_low,break_low) = [(x,a) for a, b, x in zip(low, tmin, date_index) if a < b]

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am trying to take the date and max temperature here if the temperature which is in high is greater than max temperature which is in tmax for that day[date] in dates_high and break_high respectively
after that i will plot a scatter of high temperature(y axis) on that date_index(x-axis).

high,low,tmin,tmax are list of column of a dataframe I converted using tolist

I believe the error is because of date_index as it works if I remove dates_high, break_high, date_index and x from that line of code

If its required I can post whole code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example like your problem line:

```
In [580]: [(a,b) for a,b,c in zip([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12])]
Out[580]: [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Tell me how it's supposed to unpack that into two variable?  There are 4 items in the list.

You don't need to `zip` to get the elements of the respective lists/arrays:

```
In [586]: a,b,_ = [1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]
In [587]: a
Out[587]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [588]: b
Out[588]: [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

`list(zip(*...))` is a kind of list 'transpose'

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply
I am trying to get a list of only those high temperature which are greater than tmax temeperature and their corresponding dates
and store them in a tuple (dates,break_high)
here dates will be list of dates where high > tmax
and break_high is a list where high temp is greater than tmax
I can get a list of break high like this
break_high = [(a) for a, b in zip(high, tmax) if a > b]

but when I try to get a date (I need those dates where high tem > t max )
I get error here
(dates_high,break_high) = [(x,a) for a, b, x in zip(high, tmax, date_index) if a > b]